# Updating configure.ac with a new library

Tags: autoconf

I am trying to add the pcap library to my application. I need to add it to the `configure.ac` file, but I don't understand how.

Can anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

The standard way to check if a library exists and to link against it is to use `AC_CHECK_LIB`.  For example:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([pcap],[pcap_create])
```

You should also check for the headers:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([pcap/pcap.h])
```

There is a school of thought that argues for using `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`, but that is not necessary.  Just adding `AC_CHECK_LIB` will enable a well configured system to build your package.  Glancing at an old version of the libpcap source, I see that libpcap does the correct thing and does not provide a *.pc file, so `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` is not an option in your case, and you can safely ignore this paragraph.